# Invoking destroy() method on window after mainloop in tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, splash-screen

I'm relatively new to Python and Tkinter and I am striving to get my head over how mainloop and the after method work.
More specifically, I want to create a splashScreen, which goes away after a timeframe, and then the actual mainWindow is shown.

My code looks like this:

```
class SplashScreen:
    # some code here

    def destroyMe(self):
        self.destroy()

    def destroySplashScreen(self, timeToSleep=0):
        if timeToSleep > 0:
            self.master.after(timeToSleep*1000, self.destroyMe())

    # some other code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Toplevel()
    mySP = SplashScreen(root)
    mySP.populateSplashScreen()
    mySP.destroySplashScreen(5)
    root.mainloop()
```

However, what the code does is to create the whole window after the timeframe given (5 sec.) without any content. Instead, it should create it, wait 5 sec. and then destroy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example

`after` expects only function name (without `()`).

`destroy()` needs `self.master`

```
from Tkinter import *

class SplashScreen:

    # some code here

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("SplashScreen")

    def destroyMe(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    def destroySplashScreen(self, timeToSleep=0):
        if timeToSleep > 0:
            self.master.after(timeToSleep*1000, self.destroyMe)

    # some other code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Toplevel()
    mySP = SplashScreen(root)
    #mySP.populateSplashScreen()
    mySP.destroySplashScreen(3)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: `Toplevel` is used to create "child" window so (in example) it create automaticly "parent" window - so I add `title("SplashScreen")`

BTW: if you will use `command=` in widget - it also expects function name without `()`.

If you use (in `command` or `after`) function with `()` you run that function and **result** is assigned to `command=` or use as parameter for `after`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm ...
Thanks for your additional guidelines as well.